# How do I install Archlinux on my laptop, without destroying my current Deepin OS?

Tags: macos, arch-linux

I have Deepin OS, and I want to try Arch Linux without destroying my current OS... How do I do that?

I followed Deepin OS Beta instructions (while installing), and it formatted my current files.. So, don't wanna make the same mistake again. (note I'm currently on Deepin OS stable)

Please note my current file system: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZEl.jpg
I don't know how to manage all that file system stuff with multiple OSes!

Can you please tell me how to install Arch linux beside Deepin OS without breaking the Deepin OS?

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you the does and dont:

- Never work on a system with valuable data without a backup
- Never play around with hackintosh on a system with valuable data
- Never add systems to an existing system as it will

  - A it will be likely that you have not the necessary preconditions
  - B you will break up the existing system due to various unknown issues

That said and working on a triple boot hackintosh the following recommandations

- For testing Archlinux use a live system on an usb stick/Hdd [Details here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Install_Arch_Linux_on_a_removable_medium) This allows testing and working with it leaving your current system alone, if  you like it you can still transfer it toaepermanent install, if not format the stick/partition and try another distro
- Hackintosh

  - First check if you laptop is 100% compatible andthere are successfull installs
  - Depending on the HW-age it might be Sierra, High Sierra or later
  - The hardest part is creating an install medium (min 8GB usb), if you fail there nothing lost.

Strategy:

- For hackintosh you have to have the right hardware- My Dell Latitude is after a changed wifi card 100% MacOS compatible so better save some money
- Than you need an Efi bootloader like Clover or OpenCore (reserve 2 weeks learning the basics of MacOS to get all the HW things right)
- using a 500 GB HDD use 300MB EFI / 100GB MacOSX / 100GB Linux1 / 100GB Linux2 /200GB Data/Media accessible from all three OS
- Start with MacOSX and EFI/Clover use HPFS if possible if not you have to take APFS
- Then Linux1 and Linux2 do not let it fuzz around with Efi or install its own bootloader - everything regarding booting is done with Clover/OpenCore
- Then format the data partition with a FS accessible from all three OS
- Do not install MacOSX updates (if you decided for the latest release) this might completely breakyour machine. First read and wait, if not you know quickly why its called bleeding edge.

One thing is for sure you will need (and waste) a lot of time but its fun. To answer your question NO there is noway (except a backup) to keep your files (For the wise guys: of course you can work with repartition tools and stuff like that but you waste even more time useless compared to clean installs and then restoring the backup)